# How to add new page to wordpress theme through coding?

Tags: theme-development

I am developing a WordPress theme and my theme contains multiple pages. I have added the static pages as templates and I know that in order to import these templates I have to go to the admin panel and using the Pages -> Add New option I can import the template. But I don't want my client to undergo this tiresome process. Instead, I want to do some coding so that the pages are automatically created. I guess I have to add some code in `functions.php`.

Please advise.

Comment: Why are you using WordPress if you’re not going to use it like a CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you are creating a new theme either for sale of for a client you
>   may want to have it create a custom page or pages when the theme is
>   activated.

http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/create-page-on-theme-activation/